# Data Annotation validation messages are not localized when UICulture is changed in an ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, localization

The reason seems simple enough: model binding (and therefore validation) happens before the earliest `ActionFilter` method (`OnActionExecuting`) is executed, therefore changing `UICulture` has no affect on validation messages.

Is there an earlier integration point (besides an `IHttpModule`) that I could use here?

I'd rather an Attribute-based approach, since the functionality doesn't apply to all controllers/actions so `IHttpModules` doesn't sound like a good idea (exclude-filter lists and such)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the easiest "attribute-based" solution I can think of is some kind of a hack...

Authorization filters run before the model binder does its work. So if you write a bogus `AuthorizeAttribute`, you can set the culture there.

```
public class SetCultureAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        //set the culture here
        return true; //so the action will get invoked
    }
}
//and your action
[SetCulture]
public ActionResult Foo(SomeModel m) {
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Great idea, I'd forgotten about `AuthorizeAttribute`. I'll leave the question open in case there's a more elegant solution, but your answer is looking good :)

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of another solution to tackle this problem.
I believe this is a lot more elegant than [the other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314064/data-annotation-validation-messages-are-not-localized-when-uiculture-is-changed-i/2315461#2315461) and it's attribute-based (though this depends on how you want to attach this binder to your model).

You can create your own model binder and derive it from `DataAnnotationsModelBinder`. Then set the culture before telling the base class to bind the model.

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DataAnnotationsModelBinder {
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {

        //set the culture
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
//and the action
public ActionResult Foo([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))]SomeModel m) {
    return View();
}

//Or if you don't want that attribute on your model in your actions
//you can attach this binder to your model on Global.asax
protected void Application_Start() {
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(SomeModel), new CustomModelBinder());
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```